# update a nested array with a array of id in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an object that looks like this.

```
_id: objectId,
vip:
  [
    { 
       uid:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
       time:Date,
       paid:{type:Boolean,default:false}
     }
 ]
```

My goal is to mark vip.$.paid to be true by providing a array of uid in mongoose node.js

I know that to update one single document with one uid parameter is like this

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id,"vip.$.uid":uid}, {$set: {"vip.$.paid" :  true}})
```

but given a array of uids, updating the nested documents could be simply like

```
   for (uid in uids){
      User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id,"vip.$.uid":uid}, {$set: {"vip.$.paid" :  true}})
   }
```

but this is not effecient enough, how would I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) in mongodb to do this.

Sample:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id, "vip.$.uid": {$in: uids}}, {$set: {"vip.$.paid" :  true}})
```